# Trying to catch MsgBox text and press button in xlwings

Tags: macros, python-3.6, xlwings

So I have some code which uses xlwings for writing data in Excel file, xlsm.

after i've done writing, I press a certain button to calculate.

sometimes, an error/message pops in the Excel, which is fine, but i want to catch this message to python, and write it later to a log/print it.

also, i need to interact with this message, in this case to press "Ok" in the message box

Attached image of the message box [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So guys, I've been able to solve this with an external python library.

here is the code:

```
from pywinauto import application as autoWin

app = autoWin.Application()
con = app.connect(title = 'Configuration Error')

msgText = con.Dialog.Static2.texts()[0]

con.Dialog.Button.click()
con.Dialog.Button.click()

print(msgText)
```

basically, what it does, is connecting to the app, and searching for the title.

in this case "Configuration Error"

it needs to perform double click in order to press "Ok" to close the message.

Secondly, it gets the text from the message, and can forward it wherever i want.

important part to remember though, because this should be an automated task, it should run concurrently, which means Threading.

so, a simple Thread class below:

```
class ButtonClicker(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._stop_event = Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event.is_set()

    def run(self) -> None:
        while True:
            time.sleep(3)
            try:
                app = autoWin.Application()
                con = app.connect(title='Configuration Error')

                msg_data = con.Dialog.Static2.texts()[0]
                while True:
                    con.Dialog.Button.click()
                    # con.Dialog.Button.click()

                # print(msg_data)
                return msg_data
            except Exception as e:
                print('Excel didnt stuck')
                break
```

and of course to actually use it:

```
event_handle = ButtonClicker()
event_handle.start()
```

some manipulation is needed in order to work in different codes/scenarios, but at least I hope i will help others in the future, because this seems to be very common question.

Answer (score 0):

@Danny's solution, i.e. `pywinauto` and `Thread`, works perfectly in my local machine, but it seems can't catch the message box when Excel is running in server mode, e.g. in my case, the automation is triggered in local and started by a system service installed in the server.

```
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: 
{'title': '<my-wanted-title>', 'backend': 'win32', 'visible_only': False}
```

It is finally solved with another python third-party library `pywin32`, so providing a backup solution here.

```
'''
Keep finding message box with specified title and clicking button to close it,
until stopped by the main thread.
'''

import time
from threading import Thread, Event
import win32gui
import win32con


class ButtonClicker(Thread):

    def __init__(self, title:str, interval:int):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._title = title 
        self._interval = interval 
        self._stop_event = Event()   

    def stop(self):
        '''Stop thread.'''
        self._stop_event.set()

    @property
    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event.is_set()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped:
            try:
                time.sleep(self._interval)
                self._close_msgbox()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e, flush=True)

    def _close_msgbox(self):
        # find the top window by title
        hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, self._title)
        if not hwnd: return

        # find child button
        h_btn = win32gui.FindWindowEx(hwnd, None,'Button', None)
        if not h_btn: return

        # show text
        text = win32gui.GetWindowText(h_btn)
        print(text)

        # click button        
        win32gui.PostMessage(h_btn, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, None, None)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        win32gui.PostMessage(h_btn, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, None, None)
        time.sleep(0.2)


if __name__=='__main__':
    t = ButtonClicker('Configuration Error', 3)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(10)
    t.stop()
```